# Автоматическая расстановка знаков переноса

Tags: текст, vim

Есть ли в «Виме» автоматическая расстановка дефисов? Сейчас, когда я пишу текст шириной, например, 40 колонок, команда `gq` расставляет слова так:

```
Любопытным животным является это
позвоночное…
```

А хотелось бы так:

```
Любопытным животным является это позво-
ночное…
```

Хотелось бы добиться такого результата не используя сторонних программ через `%!` и плагинов, но если это невозможно, то готов принять и подобное решение.

Comment: Вы не [это](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/how-to-set-up-vim-to-work-with-one-sentence-per-line) ищете?

Comment: Про `formatexpr` уже знал, но спасибо. Если другого ответа не найдётся, я попробую сварганить что-нибудь с этим.

Comment: Что бы правильно расставлять переносы нужно знание языка и правил переноса в этом языке.

Comment: В стандартной поставке не получится, надо же откуда-то знать правила переноса. Удалось что-то найти или смастерить, а то до сих пор, если надо текст фиксированной длины с переносами, то их вручную реставлять приходится.